# Compiling SQLite amalgamation file with C++ file using minGW-w64

Tags: c++, sqlite, mingw-w64

I'm just beginning to experiment with C/C++ and SQLite, and installed the minGW-w64 compiler and was able to get the little "Hello, world." code to compile to an .exe file and run it.

Then I added the sqlite3.c amalgamation file to the directory and attempted to compile it with the helloworld.c file, and the first result was many, many rows of errors and warnings, it appears because I used `g++` instead of `gcc`.

I have two very basic questions.

1. Is it correct to always use the sqlite3.c amalgamation file in this manner, compiling it along with the rest of the code, even though it is a rather large file. The SQLite web site states, "The use of the amalgamation is recommended for all applications" and "makes [them] run faster."

The .exe file was 53kb for hello world compiled alone and 1,015kb for the combination even though no SQLite statements were used.

2. Why did using `g++` generate the large error list and `gcc` did not generate any? I realize that `g++` is for c and c++ and sqlite3 is c. Does this mean that a c++ file and sqlite3.c cannot be compiled together?

Thank you.

Comment: Whilst c++ was originally a superset of c they have now diverged slightly so it's not surprising that a modern c file is not valid c++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, bundling sqlite like that is intended behavior.

You can compile `sqlite3.c` with a C compiler first and link the result into a binary:

```
gcc -O2 -c sqlite3.c
g++ -O2 sqlite3.o myapp.cpp -o myapp.exe
```

I strongly suggest automating this project with a simple makefile or Cmake.

Comment: Thank you. I can see that I need to read up on the steps of and intermediate files in the compliling process.

Comment: May I ask a follow-up question, loosely related. I'm attempting to use this to build a small utililty function to handle local data storage for an application programmed in a different language. Where can one learn about the steps needed to build the UI and event loops (if that's not the correct terminology I am referring to events like mouse clicks, etc.) together in C/C++? I read a little about openGL and SDL; all I need to build is a simple UI, similar to this SO page, not 3D game graphics. Thank you.

Comment: Typically you  don't write your own, you pick a toolkit and build off of that. I've used (alphabetically): gtk, qt and wx. I'm sure there tons of smaller toolkits as well. If you really want to build your own you will have to study the available interactions with your windowing system first.